# Android Studio classes.dex (Access is Denied)

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

After adding a jar as an external library, my android studio project will no longer run, I'm getting an error message:

```
Error:java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug\classes.dex (Access is denied)
```

I've tried a myriad of things including running Android Studio as an administrator, building from command line, adding from maven, or in the project structure dialog.  All to no avail.

The Jar that I've been trying to add is:

```
jsch-0.1.51.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

Therea are many reasons you might get the `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Application\build\intermediates\dex\specific_flavour\debug\classes.dex (Access is denied)` excception.

I have experienced it with my anti-virus tool. If some anti-virus is installed in your system, try turning it off (or remove it). This solved it for me.